# Why does ToOwned bound Borrow instead of AsRef

Tags: rust

If I understand correctly, `Borrow` and `AsRef` have the literally the exact same trait definitions. The difference between them is that `Borrow` is designed to address a specific situation with generic hash tables and other associative collection types. Furthermore, this difference isn't enforce by the compiler but documented as the intent.

Now, consider the definition of `ToOwned`:

```rust
trait ToOwned {
    type Owned: Borrow<Self>;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned;
}
```

Why does `Owned` bound `Borrow` instead of `AsRef`? By extension of the documented intent of `Borrow`, it must be that `to_owned` is intended to produce something that hashes and compares the same way as its borrowed value. This seems like a unnecessary constraint considering `ToOwned` has nothing to do with hash tables?

Comment: There could be a historical reason here, but I'm certainly curious about a more insightful answer.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#relation-to-borrow resume quite well. ToOwned is more a "std only trait" like borrow, you probably shouldn't implement it never.

Comment: Ultimately this is really just a design decision about how `ToOwned` should function. I believe the intent is that `ToOwned` should allow round-tripping of borrowing: `x.to_owned().borrow()` functions identically to `&x`. (Indeed, the description of `ToOwned` is “A generalization of Clone to borrowed data.”.) If `ToOwned` only required `type Owned: AsRef<Self>` you could have some weirdness like `impl ToOwned for Path { type Owned = String; ... }` which, while certainly legal, would smell pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

`Borrow` and `ToOwned` are not useful only in hash tables. They are useful in any generic code that needs to deal with borrowed values and (potentially) turn them into owned at some point. It was deemed more useful to enforce the constraints of `Borrow` on `ToOwned` for most users than to not enforce them.

For example, if we look at usages of `ToOwned` in the standard library, we see basically two: the unstable [`HashSet::get_or_insert_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_set/struct.HashSet.html#method.get_or_insert_owned), which anecdotally *is* in about hashmaps, which needs the `Hash` and `Eq` to be the same, and [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) with its various methods, which also need this guarantee, since its `Hash` and `PartialEq` use the borrowed form for both the owned and borrowed stores but need to be compatible with both.